# Xampp is not loading media

Tags: htaccess, xampp

I duplicated my wordpress website from hosting to localhost using xampp. I copied the database and the web files as in the real web. The problem is that when I connect with the web in localhost the media is not being loaded.

Here is my htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /testweb/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /testweb/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the URL-path to your "media" the same on both sites? What are the URLs/filesystem paths on live vs localhost? (It sounds like your localhost is perhaps in a subdirectory? But the live site is not? And you are using root-relative URL-paths?)

Comment: @MrWhite Where can I find the media path? I think I have the url path sets properly but I'm not 100% sure